# MVVM Where should be the TriggerAction class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I develop WPF MVVM application that uses class which inherits from `TriggerAction<UIElement>` base class.

```
public class DropTrigger : TriggerAction<UIElement> {...}
```

This class handle drop files event and should pass the list of files to the ViewModel bounded class.

In this case, should the `DropTrigger` class be in View or ViewModel?
If it should be in the view (like I think), how can I execute methods in the MVVM bounded class from `DropTrigger` class?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot give you a definitive answer without seeing more of your code. The most likely case is you would have an ICommand dependency property on your DropTrigger that you bind to a ViewModel property, then you pass the files in the CommandParameter.

The Trigger is, like the behavior, neither View nor ViewModel. Create a separate project folder containing these classes.